# Trying to pass regular expression to grep

Tags: linux, bash, unix, grep

I'm trying to exctract error lines from my log file:

I used this :

```
more report.txt | grep -E (?i)(error)
```

I'm getting this error msg :

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm trying to extract all lines containing "Error" ignoring the case sensitivity so it can be error, Error, ERROR etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
grep -i error report.txt
```

There is really no need to `more` the file and then pipe it to `grep`. You can pass the filename as an argument to `grep`.

To make the search case insensitive, you use the `-i` option of `grep`.

And there is really no need to go for `-E` option as the pattern you are using `error` is not an extended regex.

The cause of the error you are seeing is that your pattern `(?i)(error)` is interpreted by the shell and since the shell did not except to see `(` in this context it throws an error, something similar to when you do `ls (*)`.

To fix this you quote your pattern. But that will not solve your problem of finding `error` in the file because the pattern `(?i)(error)` looks for the string `'ierror'` !!

Answer (score 5):

The problem with your line is that the parens are picked up by the shell instead of grep, you need to quote them:

```
grep -E '(?i)(error)' report.txt
```

For this particular task the other answers are of course correct, you don't even need the parens.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
grep -i error report.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

this will achieve the same result

```
cat report.txt | grep -i error
```

and if you want to paginate the results:

```
cat report.txt | grep -i error | more
```

Comment: this is a so called useless use of cat: grep -i error report.txt | more does the same :-)